# read golang source code by Visual Studio Code ,compiler warning,how to fix it

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

download source code

```
git clone https://github.com/golang/go.git  golang
```

open golang by Visual Studio Code,the waring info
[image]

[image]

I try open bufio
[image]

so how to fix it

Comment: as above - you need to open `src` folder in vscode, because it's how gopls works. You can also turn it off in config `"go.useLanguageServer": false`

Comment: Please don't post just images, write down the errors and warnings so it help's others in searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Following the given link in your error:
[Setting up your workspace](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md)

> As of Jan 2021, if you are working with multiple modules or nested modules, you will need to create a "workspace folder" for each module. This means that each module has its own scope, and features will not work across modules. We are currently working on addressing this limitation--see details about experimental workspace module mode below.

> ***In VS Code, you can create a workspace folder by setting up a multi-root workspace.*** View the documentation for your editor plugin to learn how to configure a workspace folder in your editor.

And then following this link:
[multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)

You will see how to add a folder to the workspace.
So basically doing this at VS Code, solved the problem:

**File > Add Folder To Workspace > "select the desired folders"**

However, it seems to me that what you are trying to do is to install Go from source. If that is what you are aiming to, you should strictly follow the documentation and execute this installation at your GOROOT:
[Install-Go-From-Source](https://go.dev/doc/install/source)

At the **all.bash** script in the documentation you will see a line like this:

```
echo 'all.bash must be run from $GOROOT/src' 1>&2
```

Or follow this docs if you want to contribute with Go source code:
[Contribution Guidelines](https://go.dev/doc/contribute#gerrit_overview)